# Why does Rust's borrow checker complain when using an iterator returned from a method, but not when using a Vec's iterator directly?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba9255e504174afa0f31f20467caf0a9

Consider the following Rust program

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<i32>,
    baz: i32
}

impl Foo {

    fn get_an_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&i32> {
        self.bar.iter()    
    }
    
    fn do_mut_stuff_works(&mut self) {
        for num in self.bar.iter() {
            self.baz += num;
        }
    }
    
    fn do_mut_stuff_does_not_work(&mut self) {
        for num in self.get_an_iter() {
            self.baz += num;
        }
    }
}
```

In `do_mut_stuff_works` I am iterating over the vector `bar` and change the field `baz`. To do this, the method needs to take `&mut self`.

Now if I move the creation of the iterator from inline to a method `get_an_iter`, and try to iterate over that in `do_mut_stuff_does_not_work`, the borrow checker complains.

How is it that, when using `get_an_iter`, the immutable borrow stays alive for the whole loop such that my mutable borrow at `self.baz += num` fails, but when I just create the iterator inside the method, with `for num in self.bar.iter()`, the borrow checker is happy?

The full compiler output is:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.baz` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:13
   |
19 |         for num in self.get_an_iter() {
   |                    ------------------
   |                    |
   |                    immutable borrow occurs here
   |                    immutable borrow later used here
20 |             self.baz += num;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 1 previous error
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about the method call, though; it refers to the mutable borrow that occurs in the `self.baz += num;` line.

Comment: Sure thing. That's what we all love about Rust. It doesn't explain though why it works when I take that function and inline it.

Comment: As an aside (since I'm assuming this is a minimal example). If you run into issues like this. Where you want to add a utility method for duplicate code. Then to avoid this issue, you can instead introduce a new type wrapping those fields, and implement the utility method on the new type

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed a minimal example and I'd love to have a utility method to reduce duplicate code / simplify certain access logic. Can you elaborate on the "new type wrapping those fields"?

Comment: Yeah sure, here's a [little example on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3abc12a99a0a6e4c0db4b1bb0d70db79). I added a note at the top to give more details

Comment: Additionally, remember that in Rust types in themselves don't add any extra run-time costs. Whether you have 1 type or 10 nested types, it doesn't affect run-time performance

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost feel that the mechanics of the borrow checker encourage forming maximally cohesive structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust can [split borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) among fields. In `do_mut_stuff_works`, you start with a mutable borrow of `self`. When you take `self.bar.iter()`, that borrow is split: `self.bar` is immutably borrowed for the duration of the `for` loop. During this time, the mutable borrow of `self` as a whole is invalid, but the mutable borrow of `self.baz` remains. Thus you can increment `self.baz` in the body.

In `do_mut_stuff_does_not_work`, you make an immutable borrow to the whole of `self` and give it to `get_an_iter`, so that borrow of `self` lasts for the whole `for` loop. Rust does *not* look into the definitions of functions to split borrows; that would be leaking implementation details about the function that aren't in the signature. So even though `get_an_iter` only needs an immutable borrow of `self.bar`, `do_mut_stuff_does_not_work` only knows that it has lent the entirety of `self`, immutably, to `get_an_iter`. Thus there is no mutable borrow of `self.baz` in the body of the loop that would justify incrementing it.

Comment: Split borrows! Yes! I think when I first learned Rust, they weren't a thing yet. Thanks a lot!